# How to set the response content type in REST Assured?

Tags: rest-assured

In our project we are facing an issue where response content type is `application/json; charset="utf-8"`. While parsing the response object we are getting the below error.

How we can resolve this?

I guess we can resolve this by setting the response content type as "application/json". But I am not getting how to do it . I tried below ways of doing it but dint work. Please suggest.

```
RestAssured.responseContentType(ContentType.JSON); ( I think it is a depricated method)
```

> RestAssured.responseSpecification.response().contentType(ContentType.JSON);
>
> Error we are getting while validating the response is :
>   java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: "utf-8"     at
>   java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:190)  at
>   java.lang.String.(String.java:426)  at
>   java.lang.String.(String.java:491)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.charsetToString(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:482)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl$charsetToString$3.callCurrent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.asString(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:169)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.asString(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:165)
>     at
>   com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.asString(RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.java:193)

This error is thrown at the below code

```
resp.then().body(path, is(value));
```

The presence of "utf-8"  might be causing the issue. I am not sure. So I want to set the content type of response to only "application/json" and not application/json; charset="utf-8"

Comment: Can you please try with RestAssured.responseSpecification.contentType(ContentType.JSON) as responseContentType method is deperecated

Comment: I had already tried this option also but no luck. It throws the same error. I guess the issue here is , the request content type is  application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1 where as response content type is application/json; charset="utf-8". So calling any method of response object is throwing error as  java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: "utf-8". Please guide me how it can be resolved?

Comment: here is my code --- 

RestAssured.baseURI= "Some uri";

String uri = "some end point uri";      

RestAssured.port= some port;           
            RestAssured.responseSpecification.contentType(ContentType.JSON);

String expect=given().header("key","value").expect().body("status.code",equalTo("API-200")).get(uri2).asString();

Answer (score 1):

You can set Response content with contentType() on response() For e.g.

```
Response res =  given().response().contentType("Your content type");
```

Comment: Tried the below one
given().response().contentType("application/json;charset=utf-8"); but it did not work. Response content type char set has "utf-8" instead of utf-8 . So Parsing the response content throws an error java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: "utf-8"